# Cisco MAC ACL loop holes

Tags: cisco, security, acl, mac

I know this is not a new topic but need to clarify a couple things.

I have a typical office with hosts connected to a Cisco 3560-X in same VLAN.

My goal is to prevent unauthorised hosts ever accessing the default GW and subsequently beyond. My thinking here is that a MAC ACL could prevent the unauthorised host arping for the default GW but nothing stopping them adding a static ARP if they knew the mac of the GW. So how can I stop the default GW ever getting the mac address of the unauthorised host ? My ACL will permit known trusted MACS only. Is this even going to work ?

Note I do not have access to the router / default GW connected go the 3560-X.

802.1X is not an option in this case.

Cheers

Matt

Comment: You do not say what the router model is, but this is where you should put the ACL to block the traffic.

Comment: In this case the router is a managed device I do not have access to.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to concentrate on ARP, just block all traffic out the switch interface to the router for those devices. Also, remember that it is extremely easy to change the MAC address of a device and defeat the ACL. Why are you running your business with a router you do not own or control?

Comment: I am working within a restricted set of parameters.  I know this is not ideal but I am specifically looking to solve this via a MAC ACL and i except the risk of MAC spoofing.

Comment: That is not MAC spoofing. That is simply using a locally assigned MAC address, and it takes a few seconds to implement.

Comment: My ACL will have permitted specifically the MACS I know are trusted.  All other MACS will be denied.  Am i missing something ?

Comment: Then you simply need an ACL that only allows traffic from those devices out that switch interface. If you are not allowed to do that, then your question is really off-topic here. You need to control the network for your question to be on-topic, and there are too many problems with your proposed solution. That makes it an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: umm ok Ron.  I control the switch. That is the network.I dont like your attitude to be honest. It sounds to me like you consider yourself above everyone when clearly you are not.

Comment: You are reading a lot into me trying to help you. I tend to believe that people are simply reflecting themselves in such comments. I have simply stated facts, not given you any attitude. and if you are not allowed to make the actual fix, then you do not really control the network. What you propose has flaws that I tried to point out, but you seem to have closed your mind to any solution but your own, and concentrating on your proposed solution instead of a solution to the actual problem is the very definition of an X-Y problem.

Comment: @JuanCabrio Filtering MACs by itself is pretty moot. If you want to go all the way, at least use DHCP snooping with strict IP-MAC bindings and rogue MAC detection on the DHCP server. For decent security, there's no alternative to 802.1X or MACsec.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

802.1x *is* the answer here. Attempting to limit access by MAC ACL is a game of whack-a-mole. One resorts to these measures when the users cannot be trusted -- they'll plug in devices they aren't supposed to. Modern operating systems allow changing the MAC. If I know *any* allowed MAC, I can set my device to that address and have access. Yes, it will create a small mess if the same MAC exists in more than one place; the logs will be full of "MAC moved", but it will still work.

Comment: Indeed - filtering MACs is a stop-gap measure. It doesn't provide long-term security.

Answer (score 1):

I will agree with everyone else that MAC filtering is a poor way to go.  But if you have no other option, and you understand the weakness of this approach, there are a few things you can do that are simpler than messing with MAC ACLs.

Enable port-security on the switch.  With this you can

- Restrict each port to a limited number of MAC addresses.  You can set
  it to allow only one MAC.
- Configure sticky MAC.  This will cause the switch to remember the MAC address on that port and block any other.  If a different device is plugged into the port, it will be blocked.

You can also disable unused ports to prevent someone from plugging into a vacant port.